# Windows 7 - easiest way to tell whether AERO / DWM is enabled?

Tags: windows-7, aero, dwm

From [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/2d-windows-gdi,2539-8.html) I have learnt, that DWM is enabled only with AERO:

> Let’s recall: without Aero turned on, the DWM is deactivated, so
>   there’s also no more 2D acceleration, either (this applies equally to
>   Windows 7 as it does to Vista)

What is the easiest way to tell whether AERO / DWM on Win 7 is enabled / disabled? With some themes it is (visually) obvious, but with some others not (especially not when using remote access like VNC).

Is there some dialog where I can see that AERO / DWM is enabled / disabled?

Comment: If there is no window transparency, then aero/dwm is disabled

Comment: Is there no other way to tell than just he visual impression. Because if you use remote tools, this can be misleading / hard to tell. Also, when you start with an AERO theme, but change it, does this disable AERO or not? Basically I need something to certainly tell whether DWM is on / off.

Comment: Another method is if aero peek is working or not, looks like Horst Walter has another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corresponding service `UxSms` (Desktop Window Manager Session Manager- Provides Desktop Window Manager startup and maintenance services).

This starts a process `dwm.exe`. With this started, AERO is enabled (if stopped AERO is disabled). So basically if the process `dwm.exe` runs, AERO is enabled (read the comments, this means that AERO themes might, but not necessarily have be used. However, without DWM no AERO).

Comment: `dwm` can also run without Aero, for example with the Basic theme. The Basic theme looks much closer to what you'd expect from Windows XP (though not identical), lacks transparency/effects, but still uses the same underlying graphics pipeline as Aero, since `dwm` is running.

Comment: verified, applied basic theme on my W7 laptop, no aero features but dwm is still running.

Comment: Very good. Especially since it explains why I have asked the question. Just by looking at the theme you cannot always tell whether DMW is enabled or not!

Answer (score 2):

Run **SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe**, options 4-6 in the long checkbox list of visualfx

[image: PerformanceOptionsDialog]

Answer (score 1):

[According to Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120911-00/?p=6643):

> A quick way to check whether desktop composition is enabled is to hit
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and see whether windows get the Aero
> Peek effect when you select them. Aero Peek is a feature that is
> provided by the desktop compositor.

Comment: This only shows whether you really have an AERO theme. However, if I use an AERO theme, change some settings towards a basic look and feel, this does not work anymore (reliably). See allquixotic's comment above. Nevertheless a good hint +1

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the following setting in the performance options:

**"Use visual styles on windows and buttons"**

After A LOT of trying out of combinations, it boiled down to this one setting. If I disable it, it doesn't matter what else is checked: I get tearing.

Sounds strange and I still think it can't be, but it works reliably.

Comment: This does not seem accurate.  You have confirmed this is applicable to Windows 7?

Comment: It is ONLY applicable to Windows 7.

Comment: Screenshot would increase the quality of your answer.